# How to add a premium version plugin into the ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I'm trying to add a premium version plugin into my IONIC app. I got the plugin, and I added it to the plugins directory, but while running command

```
"cordova platform add android"
```

it gave me error an of

```
"no such file or directory, open /___/___/www/___.js".
```

If anyone has any idea what steps should I follow to add a premium version cordova plugins...

Comment: Before starting development please go through it's documentation for better idea about structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I copied the "www" folder from the free version repository and paste it in the premium plugin directory, and it worked for me... :)